# How to share the file names of all the files in a folder in Android?

Tags: backup, file-transfer, file-management, share-menu, backup-manager

It is being surprisingly hard to achieve. I've tried so far:

- Download file manager apps from Google Play. Unfortunately, "share" shares the files, not the file names. None of them had a option like copy file names
- Download backup apps. Unfortunately, none of them backup the file names of a folder.

Any idea to copy to the clipboard or share the file names of all the files of a folder?

Comment: Use `ls` or `find` command on any terminal emulator app or `adb shell`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif actually I'm searching for an easy way to do it as it's to tell a friend to share the name of the music files of 3 different folders.

Comment: In my opinion it's the *easy way*. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

- Install Termux
- Grant Storage permission
- Do:

  ```
  ~$ find /sdcard/Music/ -type f >/sdcard/list_of_files.txt
  ```

Replace Music directory with whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks! I think this answer will be useful for a lot of people! For my case though, it has to be a solution that works for my "grandmother"

Comment: @chelder if you want app recommendation https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is the right place.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know softwarerecs. I asked here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/how-to-share-the-file-names-of-all-the-files-in-a-folder-in-android